# what's the difference about p.a and p->a where p is pointer?

Tags: c, pointers

Is there any difference about p.a and p->a where p is pointer? or they are just same thing.

Comment: `p.a` should not work. You should get a warning/error from your compiler.

Comment: @RedX - That's not **completely** true. `p` could be smart pointer and `a` could be some public method/member of it. Then, for example, `p.operator->()` will be perfectly fine.

Comment: @Kiril yes that could be true. So i could rephrase. `p.a` will not work for pointers but `p->a` might work for instances that overload `operator->`. He is also specifically asking when `p` is a pointer.

Comment: @Kiril Kirov: Do you see a `C++` tag?  I don't.  There's no operator overloading in C or smart pointers.

Comment: @JeremyP - Ohhh, damn, I knew I was missing something. Sorry, I didn't see, that this is `C`, not `C++` and I know that there are no smart pointers, nor operator overloading in C (:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `.` operator is actually the operator for structure member access.

```
struct Foo
{
    int bar;
    int baz;
} aFoo;

aFoo.bar = 3;
```

If you have a pointer to a struct, (very common) you can access its members using pointer dereferencing and the `.` operator.

```
struct Foo *p;
p = &aFoo;

(*p).baz = 4;
```

The parentheses are needed because `.` has higher precendence than `*`.  The above dereferencing a member of a structure pointed to by something is extremely common, so `->` was introduced as a shorthand.

```
p->baz = 4; // identical to (*p).baz = 4
```

If p is a pointer, you never see `p.anything` in plain C, at least not in anything that compiles.  However, it is used to denote property access in Objective-C which was a mistake IMO.

Comment: @Alan - `p = &aFoo`, but here, the `*` is because of the declaration. It's equivalent to: `struct Foo *p; p = &aFoo;`

Comment: @Alan:  Apologies.  The line declares a pointer and initialises the pointer to the address of the previous struct variable.  I'll edit the answer to make what is happening more obvious.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can't do `p.a` on a pointer, the dot operator requires an actual instance, i.e. a value of the proper `struct` type.

Note that "under the hood", `p->a` is equivalent to `(*p).a`, but easier to type and read. Nobody ever uses the latter form, but it's sometimes handy as a way of understanding what the arrow operator does.

Comment: Can i undertand things like that if p is address we use p->a or (*p).a, and if p is instance we use p.a or (&p)->a

Comment: Better: if pointer use `p->a`; if instance `p.a`. Thats how it's done 99,9% of the time.

Answer (score 1):

try (*p).a or (&p)->a where p is a pointer and an instance respectively ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If p is a pointer then p.a isn't valid syntax.

Answer (score 0):

It's compile time error.. p->a is valid only.